# useminPrepare causing a `src` error

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

My `index.html` has:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-app="WebApp">
    <base href="/app">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
      <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
       (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
       m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
       })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <script src="/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- build:js /app/scripts/angular.js -->
    <script src="/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script> 
    <script src="/app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) /app/scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="/app/scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

All of my angular code is in a `app` directory from the top level. My `Gruntfile.coffee` is:

```
useminPrepare:
  html: "<%= appConfig.app %>/index.html"
  options:
    dest: "<%= appConfig.dist %>"

usemin:
  html: "<%= appConfig.dist %>/*.html"
  css: ["<%= appConfig.dist %>/styles/**/*.css"]
  options:
    dirs: ["<%= appConfig.dist %>"]
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task
Going through app/index.html to update the config
Looking for build script HTML comment blocks
Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'src' of undefined). Use --force to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should it be looking for css files as well?

Comment: The `useminPrepare` doesn't have any CSS files that it mentions

Comment: Your config looks correct.  You probably saw online that there was a grunt issue logged and some where helped by `npm cache clear` or re-installation of grunt after an update.  Have you tried this?

Comment: What version of grunt? version of usemin?

Comment: `"grunt-usemin": "~2.0.0"`
`"grunt": "~0.4.1"` and yes @DavinTryon, I tried to cache clear, to no avail

Comment: why u want to wrap the angular modules into one? hope you are not planning to minify the angular code by yourself ;) One should use each of the minified libraries provided then. And think about that you wrap them in a module (concat) everytime you build your app.

Comment: You'll have to post your whole code. I cannot reproduce the error using only what you've posted. Are you using inline `script` templates?

Comment: What do you mean by inline `script` templates?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv - I added my entire `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you want to concat/minify the angular sources. The documented way is to use the provided files like angular-route.min.js and include them in the head section of your html.

So, following lines throws that error:

```
<script src="/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- build:js /app/scripts/angular.js -->
<script src="/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script src="/app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="/app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="/app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

*As a side note*: these angular libs heave heavy complex sourcecode in some parts, its quite a challenge to exactly configure your personal minifier, like the angular developers did with theirs, to provide the public angular-xxxxx.min.js files.

Comment: Does it solve the problem? It is quite normal to concat/minify angular sources. Yeoman angular-generator is configured to concat/minify angular-sources via grunt tasks like the one mentioned above. So it is unlikely that the problem was with it.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I didnt know that. But I still think its overhead. Especially when building your project with a [CI](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Integration)-System and minifying the angular sources everytime, though they didnt change. Energy saving ;)

Comment: Sort of defeats the purpose of `usemin` if I have to include them separately, no?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your index.html file is in the `app` directory, so you may try to use relative links to scripts in your html.

```
<!-- build:js scripts/angular.js -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script> 
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```